# Using C++ shared library from C

Tags: c++, c, gcc, shared-libraries

I have a C library that I'm using from my C application, with `dlopen` annd `dlsym`.
Everything work fine, but I rewrote the C library to C++ and now my main application stopped working with the library.

It can't find the symbols (the function), even thow the code is exactly the same, just that I changed my compilation method.

This is how I got my lib before:

```
$(PLUGINS_DIR)/%.so: $(PLUGINS_DIR)/%.o
    $(CC) $^ -o $@ -shared

$(PLUGINS_DIR)/%.o: $(PLUGINS_DIR)/%.c
    $(CC) -c $< -o $@ -pedantic -g -Wall -std=gnu99 -fpic -I.
```

And this is how I get it now:

```
$(PLUGINS_DIR)/%.so: $(PLUGINS_DIR)/%.o
    $(CPP) $^ -o $@ -shared

$(PLUGINS_DIR)/%.o: $(PLUGINS_DIR)/%.cpp
    $(CPP) -c $< -o $@ -pedantic -g -Wall -fPIC -I.
```

How should I compile mmy C++ library so that I can use it from my C code?

Comment: basically you can't,  why did you change the library to C++

Comment: You need to add `extern "C" { ... }` around your function declarations/definitions. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1041866/in-c-source-what-is-the-effect-of-extern-c

Comment: @Galik what does that do? Can the code that's inside that "extern" wrap still be C++?

Comment: All `extern "C"` does is make the compiler use `C` language symbolic names for the functions (C++ mangles the names). You can still use C++ except probably not function overloading.

Comment: What I would do is to create a C API that then uses the C++ functionality.  This C API would specify using the extern "c" { ... }; to indicate to the C++ compiler that name mangling is not to be done so that you will know what the function names are.  This C API will also need to wrap or encapsulate any C++ objects.  Typically there is a single include file for both C and C++ and the include file will contain #if !defined(__cplusplus) so that any C++ parts such as the extern "C" { ... }; can be #if defed out and the include file works with C.

Comment: C code cannot link to any mangled c++ functions, unless you had declared them using the `extern "C" { ... }` syntax as mentioned. Also exported class declarations won't interact properly with c-code.

Comment: When you use C++ code from C, you should ideally have a C++ `main` in order to have C++ specific initialization done.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's because of name mangling, the function names get mangled in c++ to provide function overloading, if you need to use these functions in c, the declare the functions with `extern "C"` so the compiler wont mangle the names of the functions.

So adding this prototype for function `void function() {}`

```
extern "C" void function();
```

would do it. And I assume you can figure out how to fix other functions.

Comment: So, let's say I have this function called `XYZ` in my C++ library, and I add this `extern "C"` wrap. Could I still use C++ code inside the `XYZ` function despite calling that function from my C program?

Comment: @alexander: Yes. You cannot export overloaded functions, though, as this is not supported by C.

Comment: Sounds reasonable. Cool, this is what I wanted! Thank you, I'll accept as an answer as soon as SO lets me.